# What Hotfix am I missing and where?

Tags: upgrade, cumulative-update, hotfix

I have been having a hard time with my SharePoint servers, it just doesn't seem to want to match all of the other servers hotfixes I tried almost everything that I could think of as well as upgrading all servers using the executable file shown in the following picture (bottom).

The thing I don't get is that the "missing" hotfix is the same KB as the one I just installed? Tried different servers but they are all showing the same.

[image]

Thanks for reading.

Pieces from the log after running the following command:

```
psconfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -force -cmd installcheck noinstallcheck
```

#

> 12/30/2012 18:36:25  1  INF                      Resource id to be retrieved is MissingInstall for language English (United States)
>   12/30/2012 18:36:25  1  INF                      Resource retrieved id MissingInstall is The server farm will not work with missing installs. Add "-cmd installcheck -noinstallcheck" to the command-line to ignore this warning.
>   12/30/2012 18:36:25  1  INF                    Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
>   12/30/2012 18:36:25  1  ERR                    Task applicationcontent validation threw an exception
>   12/30/2012 18:36:25  1  INF                    Entering function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
>   12/30/2012 18:36:25  1  INF                      Entering function Common.BuildExceptionMessage

#

> 12/30/2012 18:36:25  1  INF                    Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
>   12/30/2012 18:36:25  1  ERR                    An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException was thrown.  Additional exception information: The server farm will not work with missing installs. Add "-cmd installcheck -noinstallcheck" to the command-line to ignore this warning.
>
> The following is missing on : 
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException' was thrown.
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.Common.ValidateJoinedServerInstalls(SPFarm farm, SPProductVersions productVersions, TaskBase task)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.Common.ValidateJoinedServerInstalls(TaskBase task)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ApplicationContentTask.Validate(Int32 nextExecutionOrder)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TasksQueue.Validate(Boolean useDefaultExecutionOrder)
>   12/30/2012 18:36:25  1  ERR                    A PostSetupConfigurationTaskException was thrown: The server farm will not work with missing installs. Add "-cmd installcheck -noinstallcheck" to the command-line to ignore this warning.
>
> The following is missing on : 
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   12/30/2012 18:36:25  1  INF                    Entering function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
>   12/30/2012 18:36:25  1  INF                      Entering function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
>   12/30/2012 18:36:25  1  INF

#

> 12/30/2012 18:36:25  1  INF                    Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
>   12/30/2012 18:36:25  1  ERR                    An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException was thrown.  Additional exception information: The server farm will not work with missing installs. Add "-cmd installcheck -noinstallcheck" to the command-line to ignore this warning.
>
> The following is missing on : 
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2687564)
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException' was thrown.
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.Common.ValidateJoinedServerInstalls(SPFarm farm, SPProductVersions productVersions, TaskBase task)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.Common.ValidateJoinedServerInstalls(TaskBase task)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ApplicationContentTask.Validate(Int32 nextExecutionOrder)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TasksQueue.Validate(Boolean useDefaultExecutionOrder)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PsconfigBaseForm.ValidateConfigurationData()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PsconfigBaseForm.TryValidateConfigurationData()
>   12/30/2012 18:36:25  1  INF                    Entering function FormParameterCollection.Add
>   12/30/2012 18:36:25  1  INF                    Leaving function FormParameterCollection.Add
>   12/30/2012 18:36:25  1  ERR                    Failed validation
>   12/30/2012 18:36:25  1  INF                  Leaving function PsconfigBaseForm.ValidateConfigurationData
>   12/30/2012 18:36:25  1  ERR                  The form WelcomeForm did not pass validation
>   12/30/2012 18:36:25  1  INF                Leaving function PsconfigBaseForm.ShowNextForm
>   12/30/2012 18:36:26  1  INF                Entering function CommonUI.HasMissingInstall

Comment: Have you tried restarting the SharePoint Admin and Timer services on this box, as well as running the Product Version Job from CA?

Comment: Hello Trevor, I did try to restart the services, and I also ran the "Product Version Job" from CA, but I am getting the same result. Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 2):

This errors also happens if you have done installation on wrong order. I have seen this issue if you have installed first sharepoint CU and then Foundation CU. it should be always first Foundation and then SP Servers update.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I ended up installing the following exe: ubersrv2010-kb2596955-fullfile-x64-glb.exe which is the Dec hotfix. A Microsoft associate helped me with it, but we are still facing the same issue. Once you encountered your problem how did you fix it?

Comment: remove the WFE from the farm and and rebuilt the WFE with the right order and join again to the farm.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when trying to bring an additional WFE server online.

The problem relates to the installation media. SharePoint including SP1 is missing something or has an issue which causes you to always be missing this hotfix. Instead use the non SP1 media and then install all the updates and it will work just dandy.

Comment: This seems to be the problem. I removed all WFE except the one, and going through the configuration wizard I still get the same errors. Any ideas on how I could clean it up?

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly then even if you removed all the existing WFEs it would still be unable to connect because of the status of any APP servers still not matching the 'new' WFE. My solution was to re-install SharePoint on the 'new' WFE but use the non-SP1 installation and then let Windows Update apply the necessary updates. After doing that it worked a treat.